# What is the significance of the unit step function?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

In my textbook in the Riemann integration chapter there is a definition:
The unit step function $I$ is defined by $I(x)=0$ if $x\le 0$ and $I(x)=1$ if $x>0$.

I'm not sure why this was introduced;what is the point of this?

Is there something special having to do with Riemann integrability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason (or at least one of the reasons) the unit step function (and the Dirac delta for that matter) is extremely important is that it occurs all the time in the physical sciences and engineering.

Basically, it's the function we use when something "switches on", but the timeframe over which it does so is not resolvable -- it happens too quick to measure.  So we just say it happens "instantaneously" and we use the non-continuous unit step function.  -- Because this is a very common phenomenon, this function is very good at modelling real life.

It's probably introduced in the section on integrability -- as opposed to in differential equations, when it's usually introduced -- to show you that it is possible to have Riemann integrable functions with *no* antiderivative.

Comment: Cool,I had no idea! Thanks Bye_World